# how to capture logged in user's name in django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

```
class logEngine:

    def logger(request):
        t1 = time.time()
        params = {'user': request.user.username,
                  'ip_address': socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()),
                  'process_time': time.time() - t1,
                  }
        return params
```

when I uses request.user.username (which is given in most of the examples in the internet), I get the below error,

> AttributeError: 'logEngine' object has no attribute 'user'

Please suggest any other method

Comment: What is `logEngine` supposed to be? A middleware? Also that method `logger` should accept `self` as the first argument (It seems you don't even pass the request to it, otherwise you would have gotten an error like `TypeError: logger() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Comment: logEngine is a class which I created to cature username, ip, process_time. The return values from logEngine().logger() is getting passed to another function. Also, I have used self. But it is also returning same error

Comment: You should provide other models also. Its not clear why django trying to get user manager from logEngine model instead built in User model here. And may be you can capture your required data without actually using the logEngine model. So clarify if using logEngine model is compulsory.

Comment: @yuv logEngne is not compulsory. Just need to capture the currently logged in user.

Comment: Then delete `logEngine` and the command `request.user.username` should work unless you messed up with Django authentication settings.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. It's working fine now

customdblogger_views.py

```
            import socket
            import time
            import logging
            from urllib import request


            class logEngine:

                def logger(self, request):
                    t1 = time.time()
                    params = {'user': request.user.username,
                              'ip_address': socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()),
                              'process_time': time.time() - t1,
                              }
                    return params

                def django_logger(self):
                    django_logger = logging.getLogger('db')
                    return django_logger
```

views.py

```
            # Create your views here.
            import logging
            import sys

            from rest_framework import status
            from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
            from rest_framework.response import Response
            from rest_framework.views import APIView
            from CustomDBLogger.customdblogger_views import logEngine
            from rest_framework import viewsets, status

            from rest_framework.decorators import action

            db_logger = logging.getLogger('db')


            class Request(viewsets.GenericViewSet):
                attributes = logEngine()

                @action(detail=True)
                def test_api_method(self, request):

                    params2 = {
                        'class_name': __class__.__name__,
                        'method_name': sys._getframe().f_code.co_name,
                        'module_name': __name__,
                    }

                    v1 = self.attributes.logger(request)
                    params2.update(dict(v1))

                    db_logger.info("Successfully entered into function", extra=params2)

                    try:
                        1 / 0
                    except Exception as e:
                        db_logger.exception(e, extra=params2)
                        return Response({'data': True}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
                    finally:
                        db_logger.info("exited from the function", extra=params2)
```